# PHP code. How $this->published = true called the article method

Tags: php

```
<?php

class Content
{
    public function publish()
    {
        $this->published = true;
        $this->article();
    }
    protected function article()
    {
        echo "<i>Article:</i>";
    }
}
class Article extends Content
{
    public function article()
    {
        echo "<i>Post:</i>";
    }
}

$post = new Article();
$post->publish();


/*
Code Output :  <i>Post:</i><i>Post:</i>
*/

  
?>
```

This code called the article method twice. when i called the publish method. I don't understand this code. How $this->publised = true called the article method. which does not look like even a property?

Answer (score 2):

Because you define the name of `article()` method as same as the the class `Article` name. 
 If both `Classname` and `method name` are same, then the `method name` will be treated as `constructor`

You can put a blank `__construct()` method to avoid it. Just like this:

```
<?php
class Article extends Content
{
    function __construct(){
        //code
    }
    
    public function article()
    {
        echo "<i>Post:</i>";
    }
}
```

[php Constructors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: I didn't notice that, thanks.